# JQuery functions with hybrid ID

Tags: jquery, selector

The following code is failing becuase of the $(id + _pan) selector. I thought this would work but obviously not. How would one do this.

```
  function panel(id) {
var toggle = id + '_pan';
        if ($(id).html('Learn more &raquo;')) {
        $(id).html('Close panel &laquo;');
        $(toggle).slideDown('600'); }
        else if ($(id).html('Close panel &laquo;')) {
        $(toggle).slideUp('600');
        $(id).html('Learn more &raquo;') }
    }

<a id="TABPAN_padi_training" href="#" onclick="panel(this); return false">Learn more &raquo;</a>
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually doing any comparisons in your conditional statements. Both conditions you have written will return true, because they are setting the HTML instead (of course the second conditional is never hit since the first will always return true)

Also, panel(this) does not pass in the ID, it passes in the actual HTML object, which luckily jQuery will also turn into a jQuery object.

You'd want to instead write your conditionals like this:

```
function panel(id) {
    var toggle = $('#'+$(id).attr('id')+'_pan');
    if ($(id).html() == 'Learn more &raquo;') {
    $(id).html('Close panel &laquo;');
    toggle.slideDown('600'); }
    else if ($(id).html() == 'Close panel &laquo;') {
    toggle.slideUp('600');
    $(id).html('Learn more &raquo;') }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### HTML

```
<a id="TABPAN_padi_training" href="#">Learn more &raquo;</a>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function (){
    function panel() {
        var $elt = this,
            $toggle = $(this.id + '_pan'),
            toggleIsVisible = $toggle.is(':visible'),
            CLOSE_PANEL = 'Close panel &laquo;',
            LEARN_MORE = 'Learn more &raquo;',
            slideTime = 600;
        if (toggleIsVisible) {
            $elt.html(LEARN_MORE);
            $toggle.slideUp(slideTime);
        }
        else {
            $elt.html(CLOSE_PANEL);
            $toggle.slideDown(slideTime);
        }
        return false;
    }

    $('#TABPAN_padi_training').click(panel);
});
```

#### Code cleanup:

- [Cache your jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)
- Write `if` statements so they're testing the right thing - testing against the HTML is brittle, and not what you mean <sub><sup>not to mention the fact that you were testing against the value returned by a jQuery setter, not a getter</sup></sub>
- Extract repeated strings into local variables to reduce chances of bugs due to typos
- Stop using inline event handlers and start writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)
- Pass a number, not a string, to `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`, so the argument is interpreted as a millisecond value

Comment: I'm afraid not. You will notice that we are using the variable id which is than told by this from the element

Comment: You forgot: why use "onclick"? :)

Comment: I see - did you edit your question? At any rate, what value do you want toggle to have in your example?

Comment: I also find the idea of testing rendered HTML text to determine an action highly disturbing. And almost certain to break soon.

Comment: @jamietre: can't disagree with you there either. Suggestions?

Comment: How about.. `$(id).data({open: true});` ... i'm also not above rendering my own attributes on HTML elements to add functionality at the client, e.g. `$('div [myattr]').each(function() { ... test value of 'myattr' and do stuff ... });`

Comment: @Matt Ball you could incorporate the action into the ID or using an attr possibly? edit: yep, @jamietre has the idea :)

Comment: @Matt Ball slide time as variable and you win. (nitpick, I know!)

Comment: Awesome. I didn't even notice (what's in the fine print) before!

Comment: Very nice. I appreciate the coaching in answers like this - I like to know why I'm doing things, not just how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="panel(this)"` will send a DOM object, not an ID. You need:

`var toggle = '#' + id.id + '_pan'`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the object `this` to your function, not `this.id`, so you can accomplish what you need by changing your function as follows:

```
function panel( obj ) {
    var selector = '#' + obj.id,
        $this = $( selector );
    if ($this.html() == 'Learn more &raquo;') {
      $this.html('Close panel &laquo;');
      $(toggle).slideDown('600'); // I assume toggle is a global variable assigned elsewhere
    } else if ($this.html() == 'Close panel &laquo;') {
      $(toggle).slideUp('600');
      $this.html('Learn more &raquo;') 
    }
}
```

Notice I also changed your conditionals to be `$this.html() == 'content'` to conduct the test properly.

Answer (score -1):

change your code, you are not using id correctly.

```
function panel(id) {
        //id is the WHOLE DOM ELEMENT
        if ($(id).html('Learn more &raquo;')) {
        $(id).html('Close panel &laquo;');
        $(toggle).slideDown('600'); }
        else if ($(id).html('Close panel &laquo;')) {
        $(toggle).slideUp('600');
        $(id).html('Learn more &raquo;') }
    }

<a id="TABPAN_padi_training" href="#" onclick="panel(this); return false">
  Learn more &raquo;
</a>
```

Comment: That's the second -1 with no comment on this question.

Comment: I down voted this response because this code has bugs in it -- the conditional problem still exists in this response. It also completely ignores the toggle element.

Comment: I just told you -- your conditional always returns true. Read the other responses and this should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @andy Baird thats  fine, but u could have told me 3 days ago when the q was posted instead of now. thats just not nice..